# Service is null when use in nested component

Tags: angular

injected service is null in nested component. how can i use a service in a nested component

```js
export class ActivityComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
    .
    .
    public accountService: AccountService //it is null when use in view!!!!

  ) { }
  ....
  }
```

```html
   <app-some-component>
       ...
       <div *ngFor="let task of tasksService.bindingSource.dataSource"> 
          <app-activity [task]="task"></app-activity>
       </div>
       ...
  </app-some-compnent>
```

```html
   <div>{{accountService.getUser(task.userId).name}}</div> <!-- <= error line -->
```

error: _co.accountService.getUser(...) is undefined

Comment: where is `getUser` method defined? also please post full code if possible

Comment: also you are using `*nFor` which is `*ngFor`

Comment: @PardeepJain it works when I use in another component's view

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `AccountService` is in the `providers` array of the module you're using or in the `app.module` of the app. In the latest case, you could also do

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {....}
```

this will auto inject the service in the `app.module`, so you don't need to manually add it to the providers.

Answer (score 0):

Önay, If you has a tipical service, you'll have some like

```
getUser(user)
{
     return this.HttpClient.get('....'+user)
}
```

That return an Observable

If you has some like

```
**example of WRONG service
user:any
getUser(user)
{
     this.HttpClient.get('....'+user).subscribe(res=>{
          this.user=res
     }   
     return this.user //<---here user is null because we are making 
                      //async call
}
```

Well, you see why getUser in the last case return null and in the first case you can not use accountService.getUser().value. `accontService` is not null, but accountService.getUser() **return null**.

Let me explain how resolve the question about you need get the data of accountService.

You can take two approach, get the list of users and then, get the list of task and map the las list using the value of the users. We need use switchMap and map 'rxjs' operators

Imagine that you has

```
  getUserList(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>("..."); //get an array of Users
  }
  getTaskList(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Task[]>("..."); //get an array of Tasks
  }
```

You can create a new method, that return a list of the task with the name of the user

```
  getTaskExtenderList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.getUserList().pipe(
      switchMap((users: any[]) => {
        //in users we has the list of users, but we want
        //return the task
        return this.getTaskList().pipe(
          map((task: any[]) => {
            //here we has the list of task
            task.forEach(x => {
              const user = users.find(u => u.userId == x.userId);
              x.userName = user ? user.userName : null;
            });
            return task;
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

The another aproach is, for each task, create a call to users and join the name to the task (this aproach is when the list of Users are very large and each user has one or two task)

```
 //we has a function
  getUser(userId): Observable<User> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User>("....."+userId)
  }

  getTaskExtenderList2(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.getTaskList().pipe(
      map((tasks: Task[]) => {
        const users = tasks.map((t: Task) => t.userId);
        const obs = users
          .filter((x, index) => users.indexOf(x) == index)
          .map(u => this.getUser(u));
        return { uniqueUsers: obs, tasks: tasks };
      }),
      switchMap((data: { uniqueUsers: Observable<User>[]; tasks: any[] }) => {
        return forkJoin(data.uniqueUsers).pipe(
          map((users: any[]) => {
            data.tasks.forEach(t => {
              const user = users.find(u => u.userId == t.userId);
              t.userName = user ? user.userName : null;
            });
            return data.tasks;
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

Well, you has the two aproach in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmr1fv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts)

NOTE: in the stackblitz I use "of" to simulate the httpClient.get

NOTE2: remember as good practice: "services return Observables, Component subscrive to the services"